# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.jdbc.mysql.Driver - Java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

so I've been learning to use conections with mysql  using JDBC API, but keep on getting the same error,

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.jdbc.mysql.Driver

here's my code :

```
package modelo;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class ConectorBaseDatos {

Class<Connection> clase;
Connection conn;

private String host = "jdbc:mysql:3306//localhost/fifa";
private String user = "root";
public String class_directory = "com.jdbc.mysql.Driver";
private String password = "";
ResultSet result;

public ConectorBaseDatos() {

    try {

        Class.forName(class_directory);


        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(host, user, password);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Conección establecida con: "
                + conn.getClass());

    } catch (Exception ex) {

        ex.printStackTrace();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error en conección: \n " + ex);

    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    new ConectorBaseDatos();
}

}
```

I have allready imported and added the mysql-connecor.jar  as referenced libraries,
and just don't  know where to go from here, please help.

Comment: Make sure you're setting the mysql jar in your classpath when executing your application.

Comment: The error message is clear enough to tell that you didn't add the JDBC driver to your class path.

Comment: The JAR containing your driver is not in the classpath. See one the related questions right - many of them address the same problems.

Comment: `ClassNotFoundException` almost always means that you haven't pointed your project to the driver (should be a JAR file provided with the DB, for instance derbyclient.jar).  You need to add it to the build path (or class path) or you may need to put it into the `lib` folder inside `WEB-INF` for a web application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Referenced libraries` are an IDE concept that the VM has no clue about. So you'll need to run your stuff as `java -cp mysql.jar:. modelo.ConectorBaseDatos` -- if you need further assistance, leave a comment.

Comment: ok, first of all thanks,  when i run my app directly on eclipse, i need allways to specify this ?  where do i write this `java -cp mysql.jar:. modelo.ConectorBaseDatos`  ?  in console  i guess  but mm i wan't to fully understand what I'm doing here

Comment: java -cp mysql.jar:. modelo.ConnectorBaseDatos is a console command. -cp specifies the classpath.

Comment: is there a way to do this int eclipse  ?  @hd1

Comment: just have not been able to understand please help !

Comment: They are completely separate systems, in eclipse merely add it to your referenced libraries and hit run; outside you **must** list every jar your program requires on the classpath as I've shown

Comment: it  does not  run,  this is my problem... i have already added it into  REFERENCED LIBRARIES  but when i hit run   it shows the error

Comment: Make sure the driver -- com.mysql.Driver -- is in the jar. Alternatively, it should be listed in META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver